# Set a date in web.xml then have an HTML file show the date?

Tags: date, jsf, web.xml

Let's say you have an Online Form where you have to Register to vote:

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
Address: <input type="text" name="address"><br>
City: <input type="text" name="city"><br>
State: <input type="text" name="state"><br>
Zip: <input type="text" name="zip"><br>
Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone"><br>

Affiliation:<br>
<input type="radio" name="affil" value="demo">Democrat<br>
<input type="radio" name="affil" value="green">Green Party<br>
<input type="radio" name="affil" value="liber">Liberterian<br>
<input type="radio" name="affil" value="repub">Republican<br>
<input type="radio" name="affil" value="None">Unafiiliated<br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Somewhere in the form I want to put the text

"Next Election: [Date Value]"

However I don't want to hardcode the date in HTML and instead want a date inserted into my web.xml file, and then have the HTML file reference that date.

However, I'm very inexperienced with XML and how it would connect with HTML. How would I create a date in XML then have the HTML file reference it?

Here's my current "web.xml" file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
 <!-- Tell faces what extension it should be using to find files. -->
 <context-param>
   <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
   <param-value>.xhtml</param-value> 
 </context-param>

 <!-- Turn on debugging for faces. --> 
 <context-param>
   <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
   <param-value>Development</param-value> 
 </context-param>

 <!-- This section loads the servlet that process faces into your app. -->
 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>   

 <!-- This tells the server where to send requests for faces pages. -->
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>  

 <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can it with the help of jsf implicit EL objects.

```
 <context-param>
    <description>Date to be shown</description>
    <param-name>showDate</param-name>
    <param-value>26/05/2014</param-value>
</context-param>
```

You can display in UI with the help of following EL expression

```
      #{initParam['showDate']}
```

To get an idea about JSF implicit EL objects plz refer the following article

http://balusc.blogspot.in/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html

Hope this helps!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Entries in web.xml :- Define context parameter as date in web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <description>Registration Date.</description>
        <param-name>registrationDate</param-name>
        <param-value>02/02/2014</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

JSP Changes :- read date in jsp as follows.

```
ServletContext context = pageContext.getServletContext();
String registrationDate = context.getInitParameter("registrationDate");
```